# Don't redirect specific folder to https in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

On my web I am using HTTPS connection and in my .htaccess I specified the redirect from http to https like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !on  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

This is working fine, so if someone enters the page with http, it will redirect to https.

But I want to exclude from this redirect one specific folder, let's say 'application'.

If I put it above the statement, the Rewriterule will redirect it. If I put it after, then the web is already redirected to https and I don't want to call redirect to http again.

So how can I exclude one folder?

The reason is, I have very often a TLS handshake taking more than 30 seconds on my web.
And the files in that application folders are API php files, which are only called from my mobile app, so they will never be shown in browser.

As there are serious connection issues from mobile app due to TLS problems, I want to call these files via http only to avoid TLS connection. I don't care about security in these files, however I want to keep the rest of my web with https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I found some solution. I used that folder as an exception via `!application`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !application [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Still testing, but seems working fine. Hope I am doing it the right way.